# Is ResourceManager in .NET a singleton?

Tags: .net

Is ResourceManager in .NET a singleton?

Comment: @Jack London: Please go back and accept answers to the questions you have asked previously. Encourage us to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the designer generated code when dealing with a resource file you can see each of the generated resource properties accesses an internal static property that will create a `ResourceManager` instance if it is not already created, and then reuse this instance. From that point of view it looks like Singleton to me (even if the concrete Singleton implementation may not be the best one, perhaps).

Example (using a resource file called MyResourceFile.resx, with a string resource called SomeStringResource):

```
// You access the resource like so
MyResourceFile.SomeStringResource;

// The generated SomeStringResource property
internal static string SomeStringResource {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("SomeStringResource", resourceCulture);
    }
}

// The generated ResourceManager property
private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
    get {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
            global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("SampleApplication.MyResourceFile", typeof(MyResourceFile).Assembly);
            resourceMan = temp;
        }
        return resourceMan;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `ResourceManager` property, it checks if `resourceMan` is `null`, creates a new `ResourceManager` only if it is. Subsequent calls will use the then already created `ResourceManager` instance. This means that exactly one instance will be created and then reused, which is the point of the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

System.Resources.ResourceManager has public constructors, so is not a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from it's usage I would say no.  I think it's more likely a factory class or something akin to that.

Being that the usage is something like this:

```
Resources.SomeResourceYouMade;
```

If it was a singleton you would have to access the instance first, and then the resource, so it would look more like this:

```
Resources.Instance.SomeResourceYouMade;
```

Also, here's some information on instantiating resource managers, even from different assemblies ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx)).

Comment: Not necessarily, some singletons will have static properties and methods that delegate to a private instance to get rid of the ugly `Instance` in the reference chain. `SomeResource { get { return _instance.SomeResourceImpl; } }`